# Titanium alloy LeftNavButton change dynamic button background image

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, navigationbar

I try to change the background image of a LeftNavButton after a click, but nothing happens. When I do this with a normal button the image will change. Are there some restrictions in doing that or is there another way to do that?

**index.xml:**

```
    <Alloy>
        <NavigationWindow id="win1" platform="ios">
            <Window id="win2" title="Window">
                <LeftNavButton>
                    <Button id="navButtonFilter" class="navButtonFilter" onClick="doClick" platform="ios" autoStyle="true">XX</Button>
                </LeftNavButton>

                <Button id="button" class="navButtonFilter" onClick="doClick"> </Button>
            </Window>
        </NavigationWindow>
    </Alloy>
```

**index.js:**

```
    function doClick(event) {
        Ti.API.info('doClick');
        $.addClass($.navButtonFilter, 'navButtonFilterActive');
        $.addClass($.button, 'navButtonFilterActive');
    }

    $.win1.open();
```

**index.tss:**

```
    "#win1": {
        backgroundColor:"white"
    }

    ".navButtonFilter": {
        backgroundImage : "/filter.png",
    }

    ".navButtonFilterActive": {
        backgroundImage : "/list.png",
    }
```